# Passing data for editing error MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass data from Controller to View for Editing but I received this error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[TIS.Models.ORDER_WORK_DETAIL]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'TIS.Models.ORDER_WORK_DETAIL'.

In controller I wrote:

```
 public ActionResult MKP_003(string id)
        {
            using (Models.AllDataEntities et = new Models.AllDataEntities())
            {
                var OData = (from e in et.ORDER_WORK_DETAIL where (e.ORDER_NO == id) select e);
                return View(OData);
            }
        }
```

Then in view i added:

```
@model TIS.Models.ORDER_WORK_DETAIL
```

I try to change in view like this

```
 @model IEnumerable<TIS.Models.ORDER_WORK_DETAIL>
```

and

```
var OData = (from e in et.ORDER_WORK_DETAIL where (e.ORDER_NO == id) select e).ToList();
```

But It does not work. 
Do i miss any code? 
Thank you so much!

Comment: If your model is `@model TIS.Models.ORDER_WORK_DETAIL` then you need to return a single object, not a collection. Use `FirstOrDefault()` on your query

Comment: But It does not work.... what does not work? exception? wrong result?

Comment: Thanks Stephen Muecke. I add and it works

Comment: @Florian: It throws an exception as i mentioned in the top of question

Comment: You can simplify the query like this: var OData = et.ORDER_WORK_DETAIL.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ORDER_NO == id);

Comment: Yes i read that but thought you get a different one for the other stuff you tried

Comment: Thank you Florian , is your code the short version of LinQ?

Comment: @TranDuyLinh lamda expression... in most cases the shorter version yes

Comment: @TranDuyLinh it saves you the select part ... and in the case of firstordefault also the where part because it has an overload that takes a predicate...